# Looking for a IP44 outlet which I can schedule and dimm

Tags: smart-plugs

I've got some outdoor light bulbs, which I would like to schedule. Also they are very bright, so I sometime would like to dim them.
Is there an outdoor outlet which is protected to an IP44 level and is schedulable (this one is easy to find) and also dimmable?

Comment: What type are the bulbs? Many types of bulbs are not compatible with external dimmers anyway. Not sure it’s easy to find an outlet meeting all criteria though. You probably need to specify your country as well, some outlets are only available for specific national plug types.

Comment: Also, do you have already have smart systems in place such as Google Home / Alexa which you can hook your system into?  If so something like [this](https://www.amazon.ca/Treatlife-Assistant-Required-Waterproof-Dimmable/dp/B086V3S2Q7) could work.

Comment: Another option is to find some outdoor security lights that have the features for scheduling as well as remote on/off and brightness control. One example is [this](https://www.bestbuy.com/site/eufy-outdoor-wireless-1080p-security-floodlight-camera-white/6404969.p?skuId=6404969) one. Of course, if you like the lights you have, this is not the answer you're looking for !